# Winter 17 - Where to customize the Lightning Navigation Menus ?

Tags: lightning-experience, navigation

Looks like Salesforce released Winter 17 in our Sandbox on the weekend and the navigation menu has changed from the left to the top of the screen(which looks very nice actually). 
Can someone point me where to customize this **Navigation Menus** now in Lightning Experience? I can't find the option anymore.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually figured it out. Indeed, the navigation menus has been deleted in Winter 17. Instead we will need to upgrade an app to a **Lightning App** where you will be able to set the Navigation Menus.

[image]